# Loneliness Lies in Twos - Looking for Feedback

Tags: post-production, editing, mixing, feedback, survey

Hi,

I recently worked on a self-funded (no budget) project and I am looking for feedback on my work. A questionnaire is online for you to fill in. Below, you can find three links; a link to the finished movie (1), a link to the picture edit before any audio post work was carried out (2) and a link to a questionnaire I would ask you to fill in (3).

For reasons you will understand, the director does not want the movie to be openly distributed. Both videos are password protected and you will therefore need to send me a private message before I can send you the password to watch the video.

However, I am monitoring my emails most of the day and am quite responsive (within 10 minutes in average) so please ask for access! Thanks in advance for your time and comments.

(1) [Final Version (after postproduction)](http://vimeo.com/10400372)

(2) [Picture Edit and OMF (before postproduction)](http://vimeo.com/10402932)

(3) [Feedback Sheet (questionnaire)](https://spreadsheets.google.com/viewform?formkey=dGRkMkd0NG9EVl8ya2VDTGZOem9MYVE6MA)

Any comment is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would gladly fill out the questionnaire.
If you can shoot me an email at filipe.chagas@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Great idea... Would love to! andrew [at] soundplusdesign [dot] com

Answer (score 2):

I have just completed the survey, well done on an excellent start.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds good.  Email me at (colin at vcprod . com)

Comment: Brilliant Colin, I appreciate the very detailed notes. Lots of things to discuss in my thesis... :)

Answer (score 1):

Same here. Stack doesn't have a messaging system, so please e-mail me at mark[dot]a[dot]cartwright[at]gmail if this is still open.